# Strange MsBuild Error (Everything builds fine in Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, msbuild

First off, I tried a shorter version of the code for my stackoverflow question but that doesn't cause my compiler error. Also, I can't user the AspnetCompiler instead of MsBuild because I am building a solution of multiple websites and class libraries. My build server setup has been in place for years and I have never had any problems like this. I have a VB.Net Library that I use extensively with C#, in that library I have the following:

```
   Public Class PropertyParticipants

        Public Property Participants As List(Of Participant)
        Private _propertyId As Integer

        Public Sub New(propertyId As Integer)
            Participants = New List(Of Participant)()
            _propertyId = propertyId

            LoadParticipants()
        End Sub
  End Class

  Public Class Participant

    Public Property Role As ParticipantRole
    Public Property Type As ParticipantType
    Public Property FirstName As String
    Public Property LastName As String
    Public Property Password As String
    Public Property LoginId As String
    Public Property Initials As String
    Public Property UserId As Integer


    Public ReadOnly Property FullName() As String
        Get
            Return Me.FirstName & " " & Me.LastName
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Enum ParticipantRole
        Primary
        Party
        Pending
    End Enum

    Public Enum ParticipantType
        Seller
        Buyer
    End Enum

End Class
```

Then in my c# code behind I have the following

```
        PropertyParticipants propPart = new PropertyParticipants(PropertyId);

        foreach (Participant part in propPart.Participants.Where(p => p.Role != Participant.ParticipantRole.Pending))
        {
           int userId = part.UserId; //this is fine
            string loginId = part.LoginId; //compiler error
     }
```

error CS1061: 'Participant' does not contain a definition for 'LoginId' and no extension method 'LoginId' accepting a first argument of type 'Participant' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did I miss what the actual compile error is?

Comment: Oops sorry, compiler error added to my question

Answer (score 0):

Try Rebuild each project of your solution manually in Visual Studio and check if some error appear. I had a similar problem because of two projects with different platform in the same solution (Any CPU and x86).

Comment: Thanks but this isn't in Visual Studio, it is on a build server in Cruise Control.net, everything builds fine in Visual Studio.

Comment: It doesn't really matter in regards to my question, I have 3 websites and 8 or 9 class libraries which all build together fine 20 times a day normally.

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is da da dah: though the MSBuild error does not tell you and Visual Studio compiles just fine, casting ensures proper understanding by the MSBuild compiler. It is clear that a bit of information is lost in translation from my VB.NET dll to the use of it in C#. Specifically the generics and the lambda anonymous functions do not implicitly translate as gracefully as one would expect.

```
foreach (Participant part in propPart.Participants.Cast<Kazork.AppCode.Users.Participant>  ().Where()){
            int userId = part.UserId; //this is fine
            string loginId = part.LoginId; //this now compliles
}
```

Comment: "the MSBuild compiler" is actually csc and that is the exact same as what Visual Studio uses unless you are using different PATH/Framework/... environment variables.

Comment: I believe that Visual Studio might actually use AspNetCompiler for my websites, I think this is why everything builds fine locally but than I have an issue when pushing to my build server.